# How to insert 10000 new rows?

Tags: postgresql, insert, postgresql-9.5, bulk-insert, row

Presumably there is a straight forward and easy solution. I'm wanting to create 10000 new rows - that are numbered sequentially with no data per row (except sequentially numbered id).
I have used:

```sql
INSERT INTO bins (id)
VALUES (1)
```

to create a single row with id '1'

How do I create 10000 rows with corresponding id number?

Version: PostgreSQL 9.5.5

Answer (score 26):

You can use the [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) set returning function:

```
INSERT INTO bins (id) 
SELECT g.id
FROM generate_series(1, 10000) AS g (id) ;
```

Comment: Took your advice and read basic SQL, went with - UPDATE bins SET type = 'rubbish' WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 1000 (slowly getting fundamentals in place)

Answer (score 4):

With PostgreSQL's [GENERATE_SERIES()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-srf.html) function, this is a doddle! These functions are very powerful and well worth exploring!

```
CREATE TABLE bins  AS 
SELECT * FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 10) AS id;

SELECT 10
Time: 294.351 ms
```

Then:

```
test=# select * from bins;
 id 
----
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9
 10
(10 rows)

Time: 59.766 ms
test=#
```

and:

```
test=# \d bins;
                Table "public.bins"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 id     | integer |           |          | 

test=#
```

Answer (score -1):

The query below can create **`test` table** with **`generate_series` column** which has **10000 rows**. *You can check [**generate_series()**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html):

```sql
CREATE TABLE test AS SELECT generate_series(1, 10000);
```

```
postgres=# SELECT count(*) FROM test;
 count
-------
 10000
(1 row)
```

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM test;
 generate_series
-----------------
               1
               2
               3
               4
               5
               6
-- More --
```

And, run the query below to insert **10000 rows** if you've already had **`test` table**:

```sql
INSERT INTO test (generate_series) SELECT generate_series(1, 10000);
```

Comment: How is this different than the existing answers?